# Microsoft Office 2011 right-to-left (Arabic) doesn't work

Tags: ms-office, internationalization, unicode

I'm facing a problem with Office 2011 for MAC, for example, when you open WORD 2011, and key in some Arabic letters, each word will appear as discrete letters not connected as one single word as it should be !!
Arabic language pack is installed on the machine and works perfectly with many other apps and browsers.
what should be done to get rid of this annoying problem ?
thanx in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Microsoft Office/2008(& later) support RTL languages?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3/why-doesnt-microsoft-office-2008-later-support-rtl-languages)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want type RTL in Mac OS X I suggest you [NeoOffice](http://www.neooffice.org/neojava/en/index.php) (it's not 100% like MS Word but it can done most of MS Word Job) or you can use [OpenOffice](http://www.downloadchimp.com/go.php?p=open-office) and [iWork](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB942/iWork-09?afid=p219%7CGOUS&cid=AOS-US-KWG).

If you want use MS Word 2011 (not earlier version) you can use some trick to solve your problem. make one document in RTL language in Windows MS Word (in your case you must use Arabic) then bring it to mac and open the document and delete the text and save the document as a MS Word Template (your desired name), then each time you need to write text open your template in MS Word 2011 (when you want open the document you have ability to open the desire template).

But you must consider that this solution is not bug free, if you want use RTL and LTR at the same time you will encounter some bugs.

Comment: thank you for the nice suggestion. but why Apple (or Microsoft) do not provide a real solution to this huge problem ? this is really so annoying :(

Comment: @Faisal I agree, I think it's because business competition but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

MS Office for Mac OS X has never supported RTL scripts.  You must use another app.  Mellel is the best. TextEdit, Nisus Writer, OpenOffice also work well. Pages 4 has bugs that make it unsuitable for RTL for most purposes, but Pages 5 should work ok.  Pages beta for iCloud also works after the update of 11/21/14.  MS OneNote can do RTL on both OS X and iOS.  MS Word for Mac 2016 Preview still not does support RTL.