# Microsoft Word right-to-left (RTL) support

Tags: macos, mac, ms-office, internationalization

I have on my Mac - Microsoft Word 2010, now … I want to write from right to left ( not only text-align right, but direction ltr).

I'll be thankful for some help. :)

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer for MS Word, but if you're cheap (like me) and just want to print a little right-to-left text, Safari and Firefox these days both support the `dir="rtl"` instruction for HTML.

Comment: Also: [Why doesn't Microsoft Office/2008(& later) support RTL languages?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/3/8546) (2010)

Comment: Do you want to write in english? Or in another language like arabic or hebrew?

Comment: "Direction ltr", are you sure? It means left-to-right. Like I am writing now.

Comment: As of right now, Office for Mac 2016 finally fully supports RTL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Word 2016 has this language feature if you can upgrade Word.

There's [no right-to-left support](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/apple/microsoft-boosts-languages-proofing-tools-in-office-2011-for-mac-unicode-right-to-left-support-missing/7876%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) for Microsoft Word 2011 for Mac presently. There are several alternative word processors that do support RTL, however:

1. [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/)
2. [Mellel](http://www.redlers.com/)
3. [Nisus Writer Pro](http://www.nisus.com/pro/)

Comment: Thanks alot. Hmm... Do you know if they have a mail which I can advice them to add this ability?

Comment: Yep, here you go: http://www.microsoft.com/mac/product-feedback

Comment: While reviewing a document, I added a comment, and the `[Comment 1:]` text appeared on the right of the box, with the text I entered appearing to the left of it. Maybe Word for Mac 2011 supports right to left text if it is specified in a file from another version.

Comment: @SabreWolfy I have Word 2011 and it doesn't support yet.

Comment: I have tested Word 2016 Preview and it still has no RTL support.

Answer (score 3):

After endless effort to find a solution the only thing that worked for me was **opening another document that was already saved** with a paragraph direction **from right to left**. Worked like a charm!

Comment: You mean another RTL document created with Windows Word, right?  This workaround is not totally unknown, but I think most people have found it buggy and not very useful in practice.  If it works perfectly for you, that would be welcome progress.

Answer (score -1):

Nevron Writer for MAC has RTL support though its not perfect - https://www.nevronoffice.com/

Comment: What do you  mean by "not perfect"?